# bootstrap aggregator force failed to connect to itself: self check failed error for singlestore db in ubuntu

Tags: database, ubuntu, networking, singlestore

When I am trying to deploy a 2 node cluster ( 1 aggragator and 1 leaf) to ubuntu using hyper v from windows for singlestore db, i get the following error:
bootstrap aggregator force failed to connect to itself: self check failed. Verify that network connections from the node to itself are allowed.
What can be the issue?